# How would I allow the user of my iphone app to upload their own photos, all to a single google picasa account?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, picasa

In my iOS application, I have a single google picasa account for which all of the application's users can upload their personal photos to. Now, I can get to the photo album to appear so that the users can view the photos that are already there:

```
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL   
    URLWithString:@"myPicasaAlbumURL"]]];
```

However, I cannot figure out how to allow the users to upload their own photos. Also, how could I automatically log them in with the google picasa account that they will be uploading their photos to? I have seen the picasa developers documentation but I cannot make much sense out of it, and I am desperate for help at this point. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Both Picasa and Flickr do not give you the direct ability to do what you are wishing. If they give you that then people would abuse it to use the services as a cheap image hosting which is what you it appears you want(I once tried the same). Flickr has the ability to email the photo to them with a unique email address and they will automatically post it but that would require you posting the photo to your server and using php or another language to send it off and its a very tacky solution. You might want to consider hosting the images yourself and doing some simple server side code. It would be more flexible in the end.